# SSIS Kingswaysoft Error in adding ListmembersD365

Tags: ssis, dynamics-365, kingswaysoft

I have this SSIS Kingswaysoft package and it came from a Premium Excel Source. I have this error output in Flat file and during run I have encountered this deadlock error which I cant seem to figure out fixing.
This is the package
[SSI Package overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJDiN.png)
This is the set up on my Dynamics Destination:
[Dynamics Destination config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Tka.png)
I have tried playing around different configuration and yet I am still getting this error upon running. (Shown in the image below.)
[Error msg on flat file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCSm0.png)

Anyone here encountered similar error? Can someone help giving me information on how to fix it? I appreciate it a lot

I was expecting not to receive any error on the run and yet I have lots of error stating the error I gave above but weirdly some goes thru. I check some data are within Dynamics and some arent.

Comment: One reason deadlocks happen is when too many processes try to access the same locked thing. You can fix them by reducing the number of processes. I suggest you try reducing your "Multithreaded Writing" from 20 to 1 and see if the error goes away. 
This might substantially slow down the load process. You'll need to experiment (please post findings back here for everyones benefit)

Comment: The other thing you could do is try and improve the processing capacity of the target (D365) if possible

Comment: "weirdly some goes thru. I check some data are within Dynamics and some arent." Yep that is typical of deadlocks. Some of your stuff will fail and be chosen as the "deadlock" victim and some won't

Comment: Is this a custom entity?

Comment: No its not. Btw I was able to figure it out. Nick is right, what I did is I run the SSIS during midnight which I know all is asleep or OOO. It went thru finally XD Apologies for late response, I just logged in.